# I just sent my Bitcoins to a Bitcoin Cash wallet. Did I lose my coins?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I just sent my Bitcoins to a Bitcoin Cash wallet by mistake. Did I lose my coins or will they be converted to Bitcoin Cash coins after August the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wait until the market decides what value exists in the Bitcoin Cash fork, you should be fine.

If the BCC fork doesn't go anywhere (no liquidity or no value), the BTC fork should still retain your coins and you should be able to spend them later.

If the BCC fork gains popularity, you can trade them there.

You may even be able to trade them both if both forks maintain market liquidity.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Cash is just a future right now:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash/

It won't exist until Aug 1st.

Comment: yah, but i used BitcoinABC Wallet and the transaction is successfully made.

Comment: Even though the fork doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you send btc coins to bcc (bitcoin cash) wallet , all you need to do is import the private key from bcc wallet into btc wallet and you have the coins, cause btc and bcc addresses are same generated .